# Why does 'vue-cli-service build' fail after creating a new eslint-plugin, with error 'TypeError: eslint.CLIEngine is not a constructor'?

Tags: vue.js, node-modules, eslint, yarnpkg, vue-cli

After creating a new eslint-plugin for a custom rule, `vue-cli-service build` fails (`eslint` works as expected, when triggered by `./node_modules/.bin/eslint --ext .js,.vue,.json ./ --max-warnings=0`).

[**GitHub repository reproducing issue**](https://github.com/aTegart/yarn-vue-eslint)

Starting in an environment with a working `vue-cli-service build`, following the simplified instructions at https://blog.webiny.com/create-custom-eslint-rules-in-2-minutes-e3d41cb6a9a0, also reproduces the issue. Running `vue-cli-service build` after every step, it starts failing after step 4: `yarn add --dev file:./eslint`, and the build still fails after all the steps are completed.

Error message:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 32 errors      

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
TypeError: eslint.CLIEngine is not a constructor
   at Object.module.exports (MYPATH/node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js:223:27)

***repeats 31 more times***

You may use special comments to disable some warnings.
Use // eslint-disable-next-line to ignore the next line.
Use /* eslint-disable */ to ignore all warnings in a file.
ERROR  Build failed with errors.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

`vue-cli-service build` stills fails after running `yarn install`, which says it is already up to date.

Most results for this specific `TypeError: eslint.CLIEngine is not a constructor` error claim [the user should upgrade their JetBrains IDE](https://github.com/babel/eslint-plugin-babel/issues/140). However, I am running `vue-cli-service build` on the command line and not using JetBrains.

The code referred to by the error message is (with preceding context):

**MYPATH/node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js**

```js
...
var config = assign(
    // loader defaults
    {
      cacheIdentifier: JSON.stringify({
        "eslint-loader": pkg.version,
        eslint: eslintVersion || "unknown version"
      }),
      eslintPath: "eslint"
    },
    userOptions
  );

  if (typeof config.formatter === "string") {
    try {
      config.formatter = require(config.formatter);
      if (
        config.formatter &&
        typeof config.formatter !== "function" &&
        typeof config.formatter.default === "function"
      ) {
        config.formatter = config.formatter.default;
      }
    } catch (_) {
      // ignored
    }
  }

  var cacheDirectory = config.cache;
  var cacheIdentifier = config.cacheIdentifier;

  delete config.cacheIdentifier;

  // Create the engine only once per config
  var configHash = objectHash(config);

  if (!engines[configHash]) {
    var eslint = require(config.eslintPath);
    engines[configHash] = new eslint.CLIEngine(config); //Error happens here
  }
...
```

Edit: I upgraded `@vue/cli-plugin-eslint` from version 3.11.0 to 4.1.2 by editing yarn's `package.json`, at the suggestion of @DelenaMalan below. The build still fails with error:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                            7:51:01 PM

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Thread Loader (Worker 0)
eslint.CLIEngine is not a constructor
    at PoolWorker.fromErrorObj (MYPATH/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:262:12)
    at MYPATH/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:204:29
    at mapSeries (MYPATH/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:3625:14)
    at PoolWorker.onWorkerMessage (MYPATH/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:170:35)
    at readBuffer (MYPATH/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:152:14)
    at Object.module.exports (MYPATH/node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js:223:27)

You may use special comments to disable some warnings.
Use // eslint-disable-next-line to ignore the next line.
Use /* eslint-disable */ to ignore all warnings in a file.
 ERROR  Build failed with errors.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Edit 2:
I deleted and reinstalled the node modules on the repro linked [here](https://github.com/aTegart/yarn-vue-eslint), as recommended by @CGundlach, but I still have the `eslint.CLIEngine is not a constructor` error

```
Annas-MacBook-Pro:eslint-test-project anna$ rm -rf node_modules/
Annas-MacBook-Pro:eslint-test-project anna$ yarn install
yarn install v1.21.1
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb > eslint-import-resolver-webpack@0.11.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@>=1.11.0".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
✨  Done in 14.14s.
Annas-MacBook-Pro:eslint-test-project anna$ yarn build
yarn run v1.21.1
$ vue-cli-service build

⠏  Building for production...

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                           12:28:32 PM

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Thread Loader (Worker 0)
eslint.CLIEngine is not a constructor
    at PoolWorker.fromErrorObj (/Users/anna/projects/yarn-vue-eslint/eslint-test-project/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:262:12)
    at /Users/anna/projects/yarn-vue-eslint/eslint-test-project/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:204:29
    at mapSeries (/Users/anna/projects/yarn-vue-eslint/eslint-test-project/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:3625:14)
    at PoolWorker.onWorkerMessage (/Users/anna/projects/yarn-vue-eslint/eslint-test-project/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:170:35)
    at readBuffer (/Users/anna/projects/yarn-vue-eslint/eslint-test-project/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:152:14)
    at Object.module.exports (/Users/anna/projects/yarn-vue-eslint/eslint-test-project/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js:223:27)

You may use special comments to disable some warnings.
Use // eslint-disable-next-line to ignore the next line.
Use /* eslint-disable */ to ignore all warnings in a file.
 ERROR  Build failed with errors.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: I understand that you have tried to update the plugin with `yarn install`, but that command doesn't update a dependency (`yarn upgrade` does). Maybe just double check that you do have the latest version of the plugin by running `yarn list | grep "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint"` (the latest version at the moment is 4.1.2).

Comment: @DelenaMalan I upgraded `@vue/cli-plugin-eslint` from version 3.11.0 to 4.1.2 by editing yarn's `package.json` and my build still fails. I've updated the question with the error. I verified my manual upgrade was successful by grepping `yarn list` again, which confirms I am now on version 4.1.2.

Comment: Can't reproduce this. I've created a new vue project with `vue create eslint-test-project`, then followed the steps outlined in the tutorial you linked and finally ran the build service with `npx vue-cli-service build`. Although I'm using NPM and not yarn, so that may be an error source. Can you provide a repo which showcases the bug for some more debugging?

Comment: I have now added a [link to a github repo reproducing the issue](https://github.com/aTegart/yarn-vue-eslint) to the question. The exact error message that repo produces (still including `eslint.CLIEngine is not a constructor`) is listed in its README.

Comment: When I download your repo, run `yarn install` and `yarn build`, the build goes through successfully. Have you tried deleting your `node_modules`-folder and rebuilding it with `yarn install`? Weirdly enough, the package `eslint` is missing in your `yarn.lock`, despite being in `package.json` and being installed when running `yarn install`.

Comment: @CGundlach I tried deleting `node_modules` as you suggested and rebuilding, but unfortunately I still have the same error (I added the exact output to my post). After running `yarn install`, I checked my `yarn.lock`, and `eslint` is now present. 

```eslint@^5.16.0:
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/eslint/-/eslint-5.16.0.tgz#a1e3ac1aae4a3fbd8296fcf8f7ab7314cbb6abea"
    ```

Comment: Could you check if `eslint` is actually present in your `node_modules`? If I read the error message correctly, the eslint-loader is failing to properly `require` eslint. The import path is statically set to "eslint" a few lines above, so the import should go through properly, provided you have the folder `node_modules\eslint\`. Maybe some kind of pathing errors where the copying of the dependencies doesn't work correctly?

Comment: out of curiosity, could you try running `npm install` and `npm run build`? Just in case this is a yarn error.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure all warnings are resolved when you run either `npm ci`, `npm i` or `yarn install`. For me the following warnings were showed after doing a fresh install:

```sh
$ vue-cli-service build

⠧  Building for production...

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                           20:47:55

Syntax Error: Thread Loader (Worker 0)
eslint.CLIEngine is not a constructor


You may use special comments to disable some warnings.
Use // eslint-disable-next-line to ignore the next line.
Use /* eslint-disable */ to ignore all warnings in a file.
```

When I did a fresh install and resolved the peer dependency issue by decreasing my `eslint` version everything works as expected.

So try to downgrade your `eslint` dependency to the correct version. For me I had to downgrade to `eslint` < 7.0.0.

```sh
npm i -D eslint@6.8.0
# or yarn
yarn add -D eslint@6.8.0
```